# Rspec command returns '`require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper' when rake spec does not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I am humming along running my unit tests. For each file, I write a test and then run rspec on it to make sure I've written things correctly. I'm using rvm, sourcing ruby v2.1.1. I successfully run the command `ruby -S spec/controllers/current_spec.rb` 
At some point, I run `rake spec` for all tests
After this, when I run `ruby -S spec/controllers/current_spec.rb` again I get the following error:

```
ruby -S spec/controllers/current_spec.rb 
   /home/eggmatters/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext
   /kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)
from /home/eggmatters/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext
   /kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from spec/controllers/current_spec.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

The top of my spec contains:

```
require 'spec_helper'
```

Which is throwing the error. spec_helper is where it is supposed to be: `spec/spec_helper.rb`

Also, when running rake spec, all it does is issue the spec commands for each individual file in the spec directory for example:

```
$ rake spec:controllers
/home/eggmatters/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby -S rspec 
  ./spec/controllers/some_controller_spec.rb 
  ./spec/controllers/another_controller_spec.rb 
  ./spec/controllers/this_controller_spec.rb 
  ./spec/controllers/current_controller_spec.rb
```

I've verified that `ruby -S` does indeed point to `/home/eggmatters/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby -S` (`which ruby`).

The Gemfile looks fine. Running `bundle exec ruby -S ./spec/controllers/current_controller_spec.rb` throws the same error.

I ran rails `generate spec:install` already as I started out issuing the command just fine. There were no changes to spec_helper between successful runs.

bundle install doesn't change anything.

What's going on? Why is rspec *all of the sudden* not finding spec_helper when it is where it needs to be? What did rake do to rspec to all of the sudden break it? Why does rake spec work and this one doesn't?

Comment: What does `rspec spec/controllers/current_spec.rb` produce?

Comment: Uhh oddly enough, that works. At some point, I didn't call rspec directly like that as it would invariable fail (this is in earlier ruby versions) so, that is that. I guess the question is why one works and the other doesn't and other commands (`rake spec`) change things

Comment: How about `which rake` and `rake -V`?

Comment: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-1/docs/command-line

Comment: I think my question is more along the lines of: I see A do X and Y happens. When I do X, Z happens. What is the difference between A doing X and I doing X? The commands issued by rake are the same commands I issue in bash with a different outcome. This to me seems fishy.